# Does typing TAB key provide a fixed length blank?

Tags: tabs

In Fundamental mode, I type a tab following typing each number, but it seems the separator between the numbers are not the same length. I was wondering why?

```
1  22   333     444
```

Answer (score 2):

The Emacs manual ([online version](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation.html#Indentation)) answers your question. Look at the chapter "Indentation" and read the section "Tab Stops".

Spacing between tab stops *may* vary. Even though tab stops are equally spaced, the spacing between elements may be different because their length probably differ.

**Manual setting of tab stops**

```
0       1       2       3       4
012345678901234567890123456789012

one two              three
1   2                3
```

**Spacing between elements**

```
0       1       2       3       4       5       6
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

one     two     very_very_long_element  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not address Lisp-related behavior when a user has called `indent-for-tab-command` and the like.  The alternative answer by @Fólkvangr in this same thread -- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/43866/2287 -- deals with potential whitespace being added before/after a tab character as a result of calling certain Lisp functions.

With potential whitespace and Lisp-related behavior out of the equation, the `char-width` of a tab is controlled by the local-variable `tab-width` and the `buffer-display-table` entry (if any) for tab.  The display engine (`xdisp.c`) treats the tab character as a *stretch* glyph.

To change the behavior, a user may adjust the `tab-width`.  However, several common major-modes adjust this variable.  Therefore, a major-mode hook may need to be used to reset the `tab-width` to whatever the user prefers.  Or, some major-modes may have a variable that can be adjusted that will ultimately affect the `tab-width` setting when the major-mode is enabled.

Another way to change the behavior is to modify the `buffer-display-table` to substitute the tab glyph with something(s) that is/are not treated as a stretch glyph; e.g., `»`.  I personally like to have a `buffer-display-table` entry for a tab that has two characters, one of these `»` (with a preferred foreground color) and a tab [stretchy] that follows (with some color added to the tab [stretchy] rectangle, such as a shade of grey).